# How to make a parent div not rendered and visualized but remain the child components visualized on media query?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, display, modern-ui

I'd like to achieve displaying none in the dom tree the parent div, but to keep the child div stil visualized by css only.

```js
<div>                    // keep this div
  <div>                         // with media query make this div dissapear
    <div>                    // keep this div

     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `display: none` on the parent will prevent child elements from being displayed, and I don't believe there's any way around that, but the `visibility` property can be overridden by children, so setting `visibility: hidden` on the parent and `visibility: visible` on the child will make only the parent invisible. It will, however, still take up space in the DOM, but you may be able to play around with positioning and the box model to make it work for your use-case.

Comment: I’m sure there’s a modern css resolving for it another way, just can’t find it now )

Answer (score 1):

If you make the second div "display : none;" in css is going to disapeer and therefore the third div too because its a inner part of the second, if you want just to not being visible just dont add any css to the second div and then it will look invisible, if you want to see a div you can add in his css "border: 1px solid red;" and you will see all of the space that div takes.

Comment: Is there a way on media query to make that div without any styles ? For example I’d like it to be display: flex; on desktop and make it disappear, so no styles on a tablet screen .